# unhandled rejection: action is undefined React js and Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to Redux and  I have encountered this issue and cannot seem to find a solution for it.

I have several  API calls inside of thunks and they all work fine. This one however fails. It is different to the others in the sense that I am  implementing a search feature that uses payload. I have tried to debug it but can't seem to find where the error happens exactly.

this is the error that I get on the screen:
[image]

these are the action, reducer and code in the search component:[image: action thunks]
[image: redux]
[image: code]

and this is the logic to connect the component to the store and access state and actions:

[image: connection to store]

Surely it must be something I am not fully understanding, I hope you can make some sense out of this.

Comment: Please post the code instead of the screenshots.

Comment: An action is just a `type` and a `payload`, nothing more.  Did you mean to look for `loadSearchResults` on the `payload`?

Comment: https://github.com/bennami/Movie-browse you can check the adding-redux branch :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change `action.loadSearchResults.result` to `action.searchResults.result`. I am assuming there is a key called `result` you are getting in your response from `HomePageApi.searchResults(searchInput)`.

I know this because in your action you have this code:

```js
export function searchMoviewResultsSuccess(searchResults) {
  return {
    type: types.SEARCH_RESULTS_SUCCESS,
    searchResults: searchResults // This is the key you should get in your reducer not `loadSearchResults`
  }
}
```

Comment: that was it!  i indeed i  am looking for that. for some reason i thought i needed to pass the name of the thunk instead. Thanks!